# Is is possible to let a shutdown script execute before services get terminated?

Tags: powershell, shutdown, hyper-v, windows-server

I am currently trying to build a shutdown script for a windows server 2012 which will perform a planned failover to my replica server when the primary shuts down.

My problem is that the shutdown script gets executed *after* the Hyper-V service has been stopped.

Is there any possibility to get it executed before?

Comment: Why not go the other way and hide the shutdown / reboot options as best as possible and use the script to call shutdown after it completes?

Comment: Hmm. This would work but as I am in a server environment it is completely impossible to hide the shutdown/reboot options. Often the server reboots due to windows updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be overkill, but one might create a service that depends on the Hyper-V service and performs the required action during service termination ...

Comment: actually it's not hard to program a service indeed. +1 for nice thinking.

Comment: thanks :) I have implemented it and it works perfectly. now I'm angry about myself that I didn't think about that^^

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft [Failover Clustering](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732181%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) technology looks like a solution :

> The Failover Clustering feature enables you to create and manage
>   failover clusters. A failover cluster is a group of independent
>   computers that work together to increase the availability of
>   applications and services. The clustered servers (called nodes) are
>   connected by physical cables and by software. If one of the cluster
>   nodes fails, another node begins to provide service (a process known
>   as failover). Users experience a minimum of disruptions in service.

For Server 2012 there are some small changes as detailed in
[Creating a Windows Server 2012 Failover Cluster](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2012/05/01/10299698.aspx).

Lots of additional documentation is available. For example :
[Implementing Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V Failover Clustering](http://www.msserverpro.com/implementing-windows-server-2012-hyper-v-failover-clustering/).

Comment: I know that this is possible but I don't have any network attached storage and I really can't afford to buy one as it would have to be fully redundant :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can try to use schedule to create an task which trigger on the service stop event, and then perform shutdown -a, do the failover, and the shutdown -r.

The keypoint is get the right event to launch the tasks, and make sure it can abort the shutdown.

also, do not let window update to do auto-reboot, use the scheduler and do the event trigger to do failover and then planned reboot.